# How to integrate $\cos^{-1}(\frac{1}{1+x^{2}})$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How to integrate
$$\int_{2}^{3} \cos^{-1}(\frac{1}{1+x^{2}})\,dx.$$
I am trying this question by substituting $x=\tan\theta$ . Now $dx=\sec^{2}\theta d\theta$ . So, the above integration will become $$\int_{\tan^{-1}2}^{\tan^{-1}3}\cos^{-1}(\cos^{2}\theta)\sec^{2}\theta \,d\theta.$$
Now I know very well that $\cos^{-1}(\cos\theta)=\theta$ . But how to find $\cos^{-1}(\cos^{2}\theta)$ ? Please help me out.

Comment: Please use `\cos` instead of `cos` in mathematical formulas, the same applies for the other trigonometric functions. There is also a function $\arccos$ if it feels better to use it. What about using $$\int_a^b f(x) \;dx= \int_a^b x'\cdot f(x)\; dx$$ followed by partial integration?!

Comment: Wolfram Alpha found the antiderivative: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=int+arccos%281%2F%28x%5E2%2B1%29%29

Comment: Please show me the full solution. I have not understood the solution of Wolfram Alpha. So, for that reason only I gave this question here.

Comment: @BobDobbs Unfortunately, $\mbox{artanh}\sqrt{x^2+2}$ unnecessarily introduces complex numbers.

Comment: Also, please use $\arccos$ instead of $\cos^{-1}$, the latter can be misunderstood as the reciprocal (or how do you call one on stuff?).

Answer (score 2):

By IBP,
$$\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int_{2}^{3} \cos^{-1}(\frac{1}{1+x^{2}})\,dx\\
&=&x\cos^{-1}(\frac{1}{1+x^{2}})\bigg|_{2}^{3}-\int_{2}^{3}xd\cos^{-1}(\frac{1}{1+x^{2}})\\
&=&3\cos^{-1}(\frac1{10})-2\cos^{-1}(\frac15)-\int_2^3\frac{2x}{(1+x^2)\sqrt{2+x^2}}dx\\
&\overset{x^2\to x}=&3\cos^{-1}(\frac1{10})-2\cos^{-1}(\frac15)-\int_{4}^{9}\frac{1}{(1+x)\sqrt{2+x}}dx\\
&\overset{\sqrt{2+x}\to x}=&3\cos^{-1}(\frac1{10})-2\cos^{-1}(\frac15)-\int_{\sqrt{6}}^{\sqrt{11}}\frac{2}{x^2-1}dx\\
&=&3\cos^{-1}(\frac1{10})-2\cos^{-1}(\frac15)-\ln\bigg(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\bigg)\bigg|_{\sqrt{6}}^{\sqrt{11}}\\
&=&3\cos^{-1}(\frac1{10})-2\cos^{-1}(\frac15)-\ln\bigg(\frac{\sqrt{11}-1}{\sqrt{11}+1}\bigg)+\ln\bigg(\frac{\sqrt{6}-1}{\sqrt{6}+1}\bigg).\\
\end{eqnarray}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int_2^3cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right)\,dx$$

Using $cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=sec^{-1}(x)$;

$$I=\int sec^{-1}\left(1+x^2\right)\,dx$$

Using IBP;
$$I=sec^{-1}\left(1+x^2\right)\int \,dx-2\int\frac{x}{(1+x^2)\sqrt{(1+x^2)^2-1}}\int\,dx\,dx$$
$$I=x\,sec^{-1}\left(1+x^2\right)-2\int\frac{x}{(1+x^2)\sqrt{2+x^2}}\,dx$$

Put $\sqrt{2+x^2}=t$ and  $\frac{x}{\sqrt{2+x^2}}\,dx=dt$

$$I=x\,sec^{-1}\left(1+x^2\right)-2\int\frac{1}{t^2-1}\,dt$$

$$I=x\,sec^{-1}\left(1+x^2\right)-ln\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{2+x^2}}{\sqrt{2+x^2}-1}\right)$$

$$I=3\,sec^{-1}\left(10\right)-ln\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{11}}{\sqrt{11}-1}\right)-\left(2\,sec^{-1}\left(5\right)-ln\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{6}}{\sqrt{6}-1}\right)\right)=(4.41-0.622-(2.738-0.433))=1.483$$

Comment: Your answer is wrong@ayan. You can check the answer of Wolfram Alpha

Comment: @SyamaprasadChakrabarti where exactly is it wrong, also please add in the WA's answer (that you were expecting)

Comment: You have a typo in the value of $3 \sec^{-1}(10)$

Comment: And you wrote the $\approx$ symbol in the incorrect place.